# Integrate Flurry Analytics to Apple Watch

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-watch, flurry-analytics, apple-watch-standalone

I am trying to integrate Flurry Analytics into my Apple watch app. My app is a standalone app that does not have an iPhone companion. I saw an [article](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/watchos/#:%7E:text=If%20you%27ve%20integrated%20your,Active%20Users%20and%20Custom%20Eventing.) on Yahoo Developer that gave instructions on it but it is over 5 years old now. I followed all of the instructions on that article, except modifying a little bit for podfile. This is my code

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Watch Idle Game' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryWatchOSSDK’
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'
  platform :watchos, ‘7.2’

end

target 'Watch Idle Game WatchKit App' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryWatchOSSDK’
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'
  platform :watchos, ‘7.2’

  # Pods for Watch Idle Game WatchKit App

end

target 'Watch Idle Game WatchKit Extension' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryWatchOSSDK’
  pod ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'
  platform :watchos, ‘7.2’

end
```

After trying this, Xcode said the Flurry Analytics module still does not exist. I am wondering, does Flurry Analytics even work at all on a standalone Apple Watch app?

Comment: The very first line in their documentation implies that it is not possible without an iOS app["If you’ve integrated your iOS app with Flurry Analytics that uses an Apple Watch Extension, you can add Flurry Analytics for the Apple Watch."](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/watchos/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flurry SDK does not support standalone Watch apps currently. It only works with an associated iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

Flurry does **not support** Apple Watch, but you can try a Flurry does not support Apple Watch, but you can try a alternate: [mixpanel](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs)

Comment: instead of posting the exact same answer to multiple questions, you should first be checking any of the questions are duplicates of others, and if so, flagging them as such, and otherwise seeing if you can adapt the answer to suit the specifics of the question.